# sequelize associations in separated files

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Im having a problem with sequelize models. I havent been able to create bidirectional associations in separated files. So i have this simple code:

```
//file one..
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  //models
  const Author = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/Author');

  const Image = sequelize.define('Image', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    author_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      required:true,
      references:{
        model:Author,
        key:'id'
      },
    },
}, {
    tableName: 'image',
});

  //associations
  Image.belongsTo(Author);


  return Image;
};



//file two...
module.exports = function init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  //models
  const Image = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/Image');

  // fields
  const Author = sequelize.define('Author', {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        username: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
          allowNull: false,
          unique: true,
        }
   },
      {
        tableName: 'author',
      });

  Author.hasMany(Image);

  return Author;
};
```

And this does not work. I got maximun stack calls. I cant even import anyone of thoose two models. If i remove the association from one of the two files it works like a charm. But i really need to have this bidirectional associations.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associations can be written like this:

```
Aurthor.associate=(models)=>
{
 Author.hasMany(Image);
}
```

Also run the following command to create default config files.

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize init
```

This will generate some folders config/config.js, seeders, models/index.js, migrations.

Answer (score -1):

Arigatou. the problem was about the sequelize.import(), when i put it in both models it creates an infinite cicle. But your idea help know i import the model i need inside that functionand call it when i need it. It was really helpfulll. thanks